# Prisma 2 DateTime field used in a node express-graphql application

Tags: node.js, prisma, express-graphql

I can't seem to find how to manage DateTime field in prisma 2 to node express-graphql app. If I set the field type to string in graphql.schema it just changes the value to fit the 32 bit representation. What are the options? I insert the datetime into the database with moment().toDate()

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars/#date-as-a-scalar) part and create a Date scalar so that you can pass it directly as:

```
input Something {
  value: Date
}
```

Comment: What I have figured out is it returns the date object which I can cast and format to anything within the resolver, it was a matter of ignorance on my part, thank you for taking the time to reply